# how to set typeface for toast?

Tags: android, toast

I am able to set custom font to my text view like this

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/akshar.ttf");
setTypeface(typeface);
```

How can I set same thing to default Toast so that I am able to render my locale text in toast messages. I am able to set Gravity, duration but not typeface.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

YOu can Create a custom Toast as:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                                   (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("Hello! This is a custom toast!");
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/akshar.ttf");
    text.setTypeface(typeface);
    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(layout);

toast.show();
```

and for more details how we create a custom Toast see [CustomToastView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView)

Comment: OO... Setting typeface to text view in custom Toast, solves my problem. very simple thing

Answer (score 1):

Toast has a method [setView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#setView%28android.view.View%29), so you can set the typeface for the TextView and add the same TextView to Toast using

```
toast.setView(textview);
```